# Request Dialog not sending requests to friends

Tags: facebook, request

I'm trying to implement a simple request option in my app using the following code

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    title: 'My app title',
    message: 'Hi there, join my app'
}, function(response) {
    console.log(response)
});
```

This shows up the dialog, allows me to select my friends, when I send it I get a proper response back. (So an array with all my friends)

But none of my friends actually see this request, I had another account open and kept inviting it, but nothing shows up on that account.

Am I still missing something here?

So in short, the dialog shows up, I can invite my friends, but my friends don't get any notification.

Comment: do you have an error code what error does it show ?

Comment: @AboQutiesh Like I said, there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this post useful:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/

And for request dialogs:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Comment: But how do other apps do it where you see a notification window popup in the bottom left? Would I need to send an apprequest and than send a notification to each of those users? – woutr_be just now edit

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an `apprequest` not a `notification` so may be you are looking for the app requests in the wrong place if I am right. Application requests do not show up as notifications.

Instead you have to see them in the `APPS` section on the left side of the Facebook page. Go to the application which is sending the requests. You should be able to see the requests there if the request was sent successfully.

And if you want to send notifications then [here's](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/) the way to do it.

Comment: But how do other apps do it where you see a notification window popup in the bottom left? Would I need to send an apprequest and than send a notification to each of those users?

Comment: I am quite not sure but check this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/requests/

Comment: The very link you posted states that Requests should show up in the user's Notifications: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/requests/#ux

Answer (score 0):

Two possible issues:
1) Notifications for your app only show up on the platforms that you have **enabled on your App Dashboard**.

If you are sending your request via the web, and checking for it on the Native iOS facebook client, they won't appear, unless your app is setup as a "Native iOS App" in your Dashboard. If you're sending requests and checking them on a normal browser, your app has to be setup as an "App on Facebook", etc.

2) Your app is in Sandbox mode, and you're sending requests to people who are not admins/devs/testers.